LFS 12.1 Build Error - Section 8.15 Building Package Tcl-8.6.13
While building the Tcl-8.6.13 package.
https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter08/tcl.html
I was able to run with no errors:
make
sed -e "s|$SRCDIR/unix|/usr/lib|" 
-e "s|$SRCDIR|/usr/include|"  
-i tclConfig.sh
However when running the following:
sed -e "s|$SRCDIR/unix/pkgs/tdbc1.1.5|/usr/lib/tdbc1.1.5|" 
-e "s|$SRCDIR/pkgs/tdbc1.1.5/generic|/usr/include|"    
-e "s|$SRCDIR/pkgs/tdbc1.1.5/library|/usr/lib/tcl8.6|" 
-e "s|$SRCDIR/pkgs/tdbc1.1.5|/usr/include|"            
-i pkgs/tdbc1.1.5/tdbcConfig.sh
I received the following error:
sed: can't read pkgs/tdbc1.1.5/tdbcConfig.sh: No such file or directory
This is my first build and I am relatively new to working with Linux.  Any help would be appreciated.
Not even sure what to try.

I was able to run an ls command and i see a pkgs directory,  then i cd to pkgs,  then ran ls,  i see the file tdbc1.1.7  but i do not see tdbc1.1.5.  Im wondering now if the directions are old and the website has not been updated yet.  Like the person who manages the tcl package just recently updated.
